# How to add product stock qty column and render stock info on backend order create grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I need to show stock qty column on order create grid in order to place an order easily when generating an order on admin side.

### TO DOs are :

1) Add Stock quantity column (Done)

2) Render the value of stock quantity

Could you help me out how to do this?

> app/[Vendor]/[Module-Name]/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid" type="[Vendor]\[Module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid" />
</config>
```

> app\code\ [Vendor][Module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by 
 * Date: 13/05/2015
 * Time: 5:02 PM
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[Module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
class Grid extends \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid
{

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'index' => 'entity_id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product'),
                'renderer' => 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Product',
                'index' => 'name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('sku', ['header' => __('SKU'), 'index' => 'sku']);
        $this->addColumn(
            'price',
            [
                'header' => __('Price'),
                'column_css_class' => 'price',
                'type' => 'currency',
                'currency_code' => $this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
                'rate' => $this->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getRate($this->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode()),
                'index' => 'price',
                'renderer' => 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Price'
            ]
        );

        $this->addColumn(
            'in_products',
            [
                'header' => __('Select'),
                'type' => 'checkbox',
                'name' => 'in_products',
                'values' => $this->_getSelectedProducts(),
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'sortable' => false,
                'header_css_class' => 'col-select',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-select'
            ]
        );

        /*20171031 add show qty */
                $this->addColumn(
            'remain_qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Quantity'),
                'renderer' => '[Vendor]\[Module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\Remain',
                //'values' => 3,
                'name' => 'remain_qty',
                'inline_css' => 'remain_qty',
                'type' => 'text',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 3
            ]
        );
         /*20171031 add show qty */

        $this->addColumn(
            'qty',
            [
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'header' => __('Qty to Order'),
                'renderer' => 'Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Create\Search\Grid\Renderer\Qty',
                'name' => 'qty',
                'inline_css' => 'qty',
                'type' => 'input',
                'validate_class' => 'validate-number',
                'index' => 'qty'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }
}
```

At this moment, using my above codes, i can see empty custom column at order create grid like this :

[image]

To render stock information, i make a block inherited from stock repository. But i don't know how to do.

> app\code[Vendor][module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer\Remian.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer;

/**
 * Renderer for Remain Qty field in sales create new order search grid
 *
 * @author     
 */
class Remain extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template,
//                     \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Text
{
    /**
     * Type config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getStockItem($productId)
    {
        return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId);
    }
}


    /**
     * Returns whether this qty field must be inactive
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function _isInactive($row)
    {
        return $this->typeConfig->isProductSet($row->getTypeId());
    }

    /**
     * Render product qty field
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return string
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        // what should i insert that?
    }
}
```

Comment: have you find solution for your answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace [Vendor]\[module-Name]\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Renderer;

/**
 * Renderer for Remain Qty field in sales create new order search grid
 *
 * @author     
 */
class Remain extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Text
{
    /**
     * Type config
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface
     */
    public function __construct(     
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\Stock\StockItemRepository $stockItemRepository
    )
    {
        $this->_stockItemRepository = $stockItemRepository;

    }
public function getStockItem($productId)
{
    return $this->_stockItemRepository->get($productId)->getQty();
}


/**
 * Returns whether this qty field must be inactive
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
 * @return bool
 */
protected function _isInactive($row)
{
    return $this->typeConfig->isProductSet($row->getTypeId());
}

/**
 * Render product qty field
 *
 * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
 * @return string
 */
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
{
    $id = $row->getData('entity_id');
    $availQty = $this->getStockItem($id);
    return $availQty;
}
}
```

You should try this